# Excel nested queries

Tags: excel, nested, match

I have an excel file that contains rows of names (column A) and postcodes (column B). I also have another file with similar data.

I want to do a check to see if the Name in cell A2 exists in the names in the other file AND if the postcode in cell B2 matches the postcode of the row in the second file where the names matched.

So for Example in the first file, if "Stefan" is the value in cell A2 and the name "Stefan" exists on the 5th row (cell A5) in the second file, then check if the postcode in cell B2 from the first file matches the postcode value in cell B5 in the second file.

I appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,
Stefan.

Comment: If you're trying to use multiple variables, perhaps `Index/Match` as an [array formula](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/)?  But what have you tried? Please show us any formulas/code you've attempted. Also, kindly see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the suggestion. @findwindow you were right. What I needed was something like this. =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE), "No Match")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE), "No Match") This is what I needed.